# Latest Virtualbox release 5.1.24 broke my vagrant boxes

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

Yesterday Virtualbox 5.1.24 was released with Oracle's `apt` repository. After the upgrade my Vagrant boxes stopped working properly:

1. NFS is no longer working after issuing `vagrant up`

   The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
   Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

   mount -o vers=3,udp 192.168.56.1:/home/retimeradm/dev/tmmgr /vagrant

   Stdout from the command:

   Stderr from the command:

   mount.nfs: Connection timed out

If I change the configuration to not use NFS, `config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :nfs => false`, vagrant finishes bringing up the box with no errors.

2. Once the file share issue is overcome and try to navigate to the site the address nor the IP is responding.

I manage to fix the issue downgrading Virtualbox to the previous release (5.1.22).

The host machine is running Ubuntu 16.04 and latest Vagrant 1.9.7.

I am not sure what it is wrong, how to fix it and how to debug it. I do not think is a nice thing to roll out a broken version or no one else has gotten such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Virtualbox. See the ticket here https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16911. I'm personally going to wait for a Virtualbox update.

Comment: Indeed, it is a bug. Weird no one notice it before release. Thanks

Comment: i can confirm, you can go back to older version or now there is a test build (117090) available to download which fixes the issue. 

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds